# TransactionScope rollsback added entities from DbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using TransactionScope, and inside it, I'm adding various entities to the context. When an error occurs and the transaction is not commited, these entities are not removed from the context, so if I run the process again, and save the changes, they are added twice to the database. 
 Isn't DbContext aware of TransactionScope transactions? Is there another way to use them?

Answer (score 2):

DbContext is designed to be short lived, for the life of one transaction.  If the transaction fails, then you need to destroy the context and start over with a new one.

The context has no cleanup capability (other than as part of disposing of the context), and it's expected that you will create and destroy contexts on each use.

Comment: I understand, but in my case, I have a WPF window, with many ComboBox where the user selects entities that are navigation properties of the "main" entity. If I dispose the context, when I try to save again, I'll get a message that the entity cannot be referenced by multiple trackers (something like that).

Comment: @DiegoModoloRibeiro - Your problem is a poor design.  You should be using a view model, rather than directly interfacing your entities to your presentation layer.

Comment: I see @Mystere Man, but what about the navigation properties? I should store their key, for example, and query the database again just to get the real object?

Comment: @DiegoModoloRibeiro - I cannot make suggestions, since I don't know anything about your code, requirements, or design.  This is something you're going to have to figure out yourself, or pose as a different question, because we're getting off the topic for this one.

Comment: Ok @Mystere, thanks for the help anyway. I'll figure something out.